# How to set the node height in Tvirtualstringtree

Tags: delphi, tvirtualstringtree

I have set the the height of the `FocusedNode` using following code

```
procedure TMainForm.SetheightClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(tree1.FocusedNode) then
    Tree1.NodeHeight[Tree1.FocusedNode] := strtointdef(edit8.Text ,50);
end;
```

I would like to set the height of `Tvirtualstringtree` in multiselect nodes. How to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no way to setup node height for selected nodes in one call, so I guess you're asking just for selected nodes iteration. So to setup height for all selected nodes, you can write e.g.:

```
var
  Size: Cardinal;
  Node: PVirtualNode;
begin
  Size := StrToIntDef(Edit8.Text, 50);

  Tree1.BeginUpdate;
  try
    for Node in Tree1.SelectedNodes do
      Tree1.NodeHeight[Node] := Size;
  finally
    Tree1.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```